# How can I get compose back on ibus?

Tags: 11.04, ibus

I can't seem to get Compose in Ibus since I upgraded to Natty, and the unicode option doesn't cut it. I cannot enter custom latin characters with the unicode option :/.

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the upgrade to Natty had removed the compose package, and I didn't know this. Fixed it by reinstalling compose :)!

óĺá!