# Some entries in ~/.XCompose are ignored. How can I fix that?

Tags: compose-key

For some reason, I can no longer add custom Compose key sequences. I have the file .XCompose in my home folder with content like

```
<Multi_key> <equal> <asciitilde>     : "≅"
<Multi_key> <underscore> <slash>     : "∠"
<Multi_key> <slash> <underscore>     : "∠"
```

etc.

Default sequences like the ones that make « á », etc. work.

Comment: GNOME applications (which constitute a majority of the Ubuntu desktop) don't adhere to the standard compose bindings. To fix this you have to change the input method for all GNOME apps. Have you tried following the instructions outlined in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence)?

Comment: yes, that worked!