# Custom composer key combination + Anthy

Tags: keyboard, input-method

I am able to use custom composer key sequence like described here:
[How can I add a custom compose key sequence?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence)

Using this method needs to export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim". But doing so will disable IBus Anthy input for me.

Is there a way to have the sweetness of both, customized composer key sequences AND IBus Anthy input?

During research I have read that composer key sequences in Gnome are hardcoded in gtk+-2.10.7/gtk/gtkimcontextsimple.c, so editing and recompiling might work, although I do not want to resort to such a method yet...

Edit: I don't need Anthy working with the custom composer keys, basically I want to have two input Methods: Japanese Anthy and EN_UK (with the composer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the same observation. IBus, which is enabled by default in Ubuntu, has some built-in compose table rules, but at the same time it seems to disable [the functionality provided by libx11](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/Compose.5.html).

From some sources it's said that `~/.XCompose` is recognized together with uim. So a possible solution for you (untested) might be to install and enable the uim IM framework and start using uim-anthy instead of ibus-anthy.

*Edit:*

I was curious, so I tested. uim seems to work. Can't tell how convenient it is to use Anthy with uim instead of ibus, though.