# How to use Compose Key with ~/.XCompose on 19.10?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, compose-key

I'm trying to get compose key working and have successfully enabled the builtin ones via gnome tweak tool (e.g. `<Multi_key> , <o> , <o>` works).

However I cannot get `~/.XCompose` to be recognized, I've tried using the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence) but it doesn't work either with `xim`, `uim` or `gtk-im-context-simple`.

I've tried using [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59629/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-xcompose-file-has-loaded) to debug but I've been unable to get `~/.XCompose` to be read at all with any of the above options.

Does anyone know of a way to use `~/.XCompose`, or know of a different way to register custom compose key sequences on Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out to get `~/.XCompose` updates to occur one needs to restart `ibus` using `ibus restart`.