# Can æ with a macron be obtained with the compose key?

Tags: keyboard-layout, compose-key

I have enabled the compose key using the standard GNOME `[Compose][a][e]` gives æ; `[compose][-][a]` gives `ā`; `[compose][-][a][e]` gives `āe`, and `[compose][a][e][-]` gives `æ-`; is it possible, however, to obtain æ with a macron as it is to obtain e.g. `ā`, `ē`, &c.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. One built-in way to do it is:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>_</kbd> followed by <kbd>æ</kbd> => ǣ

But if you don't have æ easily accessible in the keyboard layout you are using, you can create an `~/.XCompose` file as [Characters writing](https://askubuntu.com/users/685331/characters-writing) mentioned and add for instance this line:

```
<Multi_key> <underscore> <a> <e> : "ǣ" U01E3 # LATIN SMALL LETTER AE WITH MACRON
```

At next login you should be able to do:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>_</kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>E</kbd> => ǣ

Comment: Thank you; I followed the latter method. I'd've upvoted you had I been able to but you'll have to make do with the knowledge that you've helped someone to copy out some tables of Old English inflexion/pronunciation.

Comment: @AnagramAtaf: Good to hear that you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get by first typing an æ, then pressing control-alt-u, then typing 304, and then pressing space: ǣ. It looks better in some fonts than in others. It might be possible to get the compose key to work the way you suggest, but I haven't tried it. For that, I'd read the answers to this other question: [How can I add a custom compose key sequence?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence?rq=1) I hope that's enough, otherwise I hope someone can read those answers and adapt them for this.

Edit: As Gunnar Hjalmarsson says, you could press control-shift U, type 1e3, then press space, and that would write ǣ without having to type the æ as a separate character.

Comment: Please note that ǣ exists as unicode U01E3. So <Ctrl>+<Shift>+U followed by 01e3 works.