# How can I make IBus not ignore ~/.XCompose?

Tags: ibus, xinput, input-method

Since UIM didn't want to play ball after installing Ubuntu 12.04 from scratch, I tried IBus, since that's the IME framework that's coming with Ubuntu by default.

However, *ibus-table-compose* is a pain in the butt to use because just to enter one character I need to press the key combination to trigger IBus first, enter the respective compose sequence, then press the IBus key combination again to disable it. Instead of that I'd rather like to keep my compose key functionality as provided by XIM, since that requires fewer keystrokes.

The problem is, though, that when the default input method is set to IBus and IBus is deactivated so that (AIUI, since I started it with *ibus-daemon --xim*) it is bypassed in favor of XIM, the settings in `~/.XCompose` seem to be overridden by IBus's own version, so e.g. *Compose c a* doesn't give *ą* (a-ogonek) as I defined in the *.XCompose* file in my home directory, but *ǎ* (a-hacek), as defined by some other settings.

I've grown quite accustomed to my own mnemnonics, so is there any way to make my system use my own `~/.XCompose` file with the default input method still being set to IBus so that IBus will still work e.g. in OpenOffice and other applications that don't let you choose the input method with a context menu?

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of the question [How can I get compose back on ibus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36168/how-can-i-get-compose-back-on-ibus)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

`ibus` works now with `.XCompose` file: https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1876

**Previous Answer (still works)**

As stated by @von, you could not use `.XCompose` with IBUS for some years.

In the case your distro is still old, you can use [`uim`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uim) as Input Method, which supports Unicode, both GTK+ and Qt immodules with legacy [`XIM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xim) support.

A good way to handle your `.XCompose` and keep existing global Compose is:

1. Install uim:

   `sudo apt-get install uim`
2. Make it the default Input Method:

   `im-config -n uim`
3. Edit your `.XCompose` and add the current keyboard locale (in my case, `en_US`) as **first line**:

   `include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"`
4. Done! Restart the programs you want to start to get your `.XCompose` file.

**Known Issues**

Ubuntu Unity Dash will never produces a cedilla.

**Other Distros**

I played a bit with `.XCompose` and Input Methods on modern distros these days, while trying make Linux keep the same keyboard behavior as Windows(TM) for latin languages (output `ç` instead of `ć`, no accented consonants, etc).

I created a repo with this instructions (for Ubuntu and other distributions too): https://github.com/raelgc/win_us_intl

Comment: What exactly "you CANNOT use your .XCompose with IBUS for now" means? What have changed? Was this change in the Ubuntu itself or in something that Ubuntu uses?

Comment: @AndreyRybak IBUS is newest then `XIM` and `uim` and doesn't support `.XCompose` files yet (and I'm not sure if that will change, as one year later still the same status). No, it's not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: It seems to be working for me in 16.04 (with Gnome).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You mean, IBUS and .XCompose? Just crossing my fingers that this get fixed 4 years since my above answer.

Comment: Yes. I had a small `~/.Xcompose` with working entries. I added a bunch of new entries, they didn't function, then I did `ibus restart` and all the new ones worked.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I tested here in Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity - when not writing in English, I use brazilian portuguese, i.e., latin language - and all latin combinations didn't work for me with `ibus`. My `.XCompose` file is bit large to mimic Windows. I still need to test remove the `include` line to see if it's related (maybe the `include` works with `uim` but not with `ibus`).

Comment: I second @DennisWilliamson, it works on Ubuntu-MATE 20.04. Glad to see ibus is finally friends with .XCompose :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since Dennis Williamson said it worked in 16.04 in a comment above, I tested in this fresh 18.04 install with a short `.XCompose` copied from my previous 16.04 install.

```
# Import default rules from the system Compose file
include "%L"

# Custom definitions
<Multi_key> <R> <R> <R>             : "ʁ"   U0281 # LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL INVERTED R
```

Then I ran `ibus restart` in a terminal and I can type ʁ.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, though, that when the default input method is set to IBus and IBus is deactivated so that (AIUI, since I started it with ibus-daemon --xim) it is bypassed in favor of XIM, the settings in ~/.XCompose seem to be overridden by IBus's own version, so e.g. Compose c a doesn't give ą (a-ogonek) as I defined in the .XCompose file in my home directory, but ǎ (a-hacek), as defined by some other settings.

It appears that it is not defined by some other settings, in the sense of some configuration file you might edit. It appears that it is compiled in, hard-coded in the file `gtkimcontextsimpleseqs.h`. It further appears that it's not easy to customize the `gtk_compose_seqs_compact` array in that file and add your own Compose key sequences. The table is optimized for space, not easy editiability. So the "simply change the source and recompile" strategy may be more difficult than I thought.

> I've grown quite accustomed to my own mnemnonics, so is there any way to make my system use my own ~/.XCompose file with the default input method still being set to IBus so that IBus will still work e.g. in OpenOffice and other applications that don't let you choose the input method with a context menu?

There is a bug report at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155010 which has a patch that (they say) would make it possible to customize the compose table. It still wouldn't use your ~/.XCompose file, and the syntax would be different, but it's something. But I note that the bug in question is still open, so I guess this has not made it into the official releases yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set globally *(i.e. for Ubuntu in `/etc/environment`)* the `QT_IM_MODULE`, `GTK_IM_MODULE` variables *(the last unneeded for gnome)* to `ibus`, and `XMODIFIERS` to `@im=ibus`.

2.α Execute `setxkbmap` with `-option` to choose compose key. E.g. to use the right logo key: `setxkbmap -option compose:rwin`. This would be overwritten on reboot.

2.β To retain the setting on reboot, create the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbOptions"    "compose:rwin"
EndSection
```

Tested, and works for both X11 and *(at least the `setxkbmap` way)* Wayland.

Thanks for [a hint goes to fujiwarat](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1876#issuecomment-253170102), updated per [this discussion](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1877).

Comment: Changing system-wide config is crazy though. Just put 2alpha and those environment variables in your .xprofile or .xinitrc whichever one it is you're using.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist err… lol, what?? Make me unsee it — you first made pared down version of my answer, then downvoted mine one for addition which your answer doesn't have *(how are you going to retain the config on reboot dude?)*, and which is optional *(as you can see by enumeration and the explanation)*.

Comment: Someone can't take criticism... Hey do you have orange hair, by any chance?

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist lol you didn't do a critique. You copied my answer, then downvoted mine to be on top. It could've even worked if you didn't leave the comment, so I noticed, and flagged your answer. As for the content of your comment — I already replied. And sorry, I didn't get — what is the orange-hairs joke about?