# Configure ibus to generate "à" using Compose + a + `

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, ibus, input, compose-key

I would like to have ibus work like to corresponding system in OS X.

In order to get an "à" in a text field I want to make these steps:

1. I press the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key
2. I press the <kbd>a</kbd> key
3. (an "a" appear in the text field with a yellow background)
4. (a menu of possible accented "a" letters appears)
5. I press the <kbd>`</kbd> key
6. (an "à" appears and the yellow background behind the character disappear)
7. (the menu disappear and I am no longer in the "Composite mode" and can continue writing text)

How can I configure ibus in Precise 12.04 to get this result?

Comment: And why you just don't press '`' and then 'a'?

Comment: Because in my mind I see "à" as "a plus accent", not "accent plus a". Anyway, I would like ibus to give me the same result for "_grave_" + "a" and "a" + "_grave_", as the OS X compositing system does.

Comment: @gioele I'm running 12.04 and **Compose** then **a** then **Accent** does the trick for me, though I don't have a yellow background option, I didn't need to configure it in a special way for it to work that way around. Maybe give us your key-binds and keyboard layout, might be something to do with language differences.

Comment: @Oyibo: does the compose mode goes away after you press the accent? in my case ibus remains in compose mode.

Comment: @gioele Yes it leaves it once I've pressed the accent I'd like.

Comment: @Oyibo what ibus input method are you using?

Comment: @gioele the default one on 12.04, not sure which it is :P

Answer (score 0):

ibus supports input with plain old XCompose, i.e. without the compose-table method. To configure ibus to work with XCompose [follow this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/836035/266507).

Then you can start using it with no additional movement, the system Compose file have already defined the combinations on both order.

But just in case if you'd want to add something more, you can create a `~/.XCompose` file. You can also download a popular XCompose, [like this one](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose/blob/master/dotXCompose), and then edit to suit your needs, but watch out for dragons, i.e. the one I linked have the combination you want redefined to input a `LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL A`. Also note: I don't know out of hands if there's a way to reload the file without logging out/logging in. `ibus restart` for some reason doesn't work, [I reported a bug](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1877).